# How to troubleshoot a SharePoint Add-In that is stuck on "We're adding your app"?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'd like to add a SharePoint Hosted Add-In from the AppCatalog to a SharePoint 2016 on-premises Website, but in the Site Contents of that Website the SharePoint Hosted Add-In is stuck being grey with the message "We're adding your app".

I have the SharePoint Environment Configured as described in [SharePoint 2016 : A Deep Dive into SharePoint Add-in Environment Configuration and SharePoint Hosted Add-in Creation and Upgrade](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37238.sharepoint-2016-a-deep-dive-into-sharepoint-add-in-environment-configuration-and-sharepoint-hosted-add-in-creation-and-upgrade.aspx), I have checked the windows services and both `SharePoint Administration` and `SharePoint Timer Service` are running.

So, how can I get the SharePoint Add-In to be successfully added to the SharePoint Website?